# How to mark candle stick which is not surpassed MA50

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading

I am trying to set data labels for candle stick which only has shadow cross MA50. Could you please show me the code for this. Thank you very much!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3D9Rz.png)

Answer (score 0):

The code below will plot what you asked, but instead of using labels, you might want to consider using `bgcolor()`. The number of labels on a chart is limited, while `bgcolor()` does not have that limitation.

```
//@version=4
study("My Script", overlay=true)

src     = input(close, "Source", type=input.source)
len     = input(50, "Moving average length", type=input.integer, minval=1)

ma      = sma(src, len)
show    = barstate.isconfirmed and high > ma and max(open,close) < ma

if show
    label.new(bar_index, high, "V", yloc=yloc.abovebar)

bgcolor(show ? color.yellow : na)
plot(ma, "SMA")
```

This screenshot demonstrates that you can see the labels stop being produced if you go back far enough on your chart:
[image: Labels gone]